# Django REST API Listview

Tags: django, rest, web

Currently I'm trying to develop personal blog with Django/REST API, and I have trouble for that.

There are a number of posts in blog and I want to control those posts with Hyperlink. I made it by using ModelViewSet, however, whole data in detailView is also shown in ListView.

The thing is, I only want "url" and "title" of posts to be shown in ListView while DetailView contains full data. 
Here is my code and current results given by REST framework.
Don't mind IndexView

```
# serializers
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

# views
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser, )
```

**Post List in REST API:**

[image]

**Post instance in REST API:**

[image]

Comment: Don't post code as images

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you need a separate serializer for the list view.

You could create a custom serializer that takes in a `fields` arg to select specific fields. But its probably simpler to just have a separate one for the `ListView`. Also, for the list view, if you are only showing a subset of the model fields, you can use the `only()` function on the queryset to only return the model data that you need. For example:

`qs = MyModel.objects.all().only('field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c')`

Here is the custom serializer if you decide to go that way:

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        selected_fields = kwargs.pop('selected_fields', None)

        # used pop function so selected_fields is not passed to superclass
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if selected_fields:
            # make sure only fields for the model are allowed
            fields = set(selected_fields)
            current_fields = set(self.fields.keys())
            for field in current_fields - fields:
                self.fields.pop(field)

class MyModelSerializer(CustomSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

In the list view:

```
required_fields = ('field_a', 'field_b', 'field_c')
data_to_return = MyModelSerializer(model_queryset, many=True, fields=required_fields).data
return Response(data)
```